# Why these backspace are not printing

Tags: java, backspace

I am trying to get factorial of given integer with the below code, but the final `\b` is not printing. Why?

```
import java.util.*;

class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("INPUT AN INTEGER");
        int num = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print(num + "!=");
        for(int i = num; i > 0; i = i - 1){
            System.out.print(i + "*");
        }
        System.out.print("\b");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're wanting the backspace to clear existing text? That only works in some consoles.

Comment: No i want to clear only last *

Comment: @Yesitha the last * still qualifies as "existing text"

Comment: @Yesitha Ya, not all consoles support printing backspaces to remove text. I've noticed that consoles in IDEs especially tend not to support it.

Comment: No when i practice another code,it worked.

Comment: I want to get factorial if i insert 4 ,output= 4!=4*3*2*1

Comment: @Yesitha Try adding a call to `System.out.flush()` after printing the backspace then. The backspace may be getting stuck in the output buffer since you aren't printing newlines.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Didnt work same output as earlier

Comment: use ``` System.out.print("  "); ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated, the functionality of various output terminals varies wildly. There are full fledged VT100 terminals, Windows command line prompts, views within IDE's etc. So backspace is likely not supported by every one of them.

However, you should not generate text *unless* it is required. Do not backtrace or - in this case - backspace *after* the fact. That's an error prone process, and you use more memory resources by first creating the string in the first place. The latter is not a problem for a single `*`, but in general you try and avoid spurious memory use.

---

The following code should work:

```
for (int i = num; i > 0; i--){
    if (i != num) {
        print("*");
    }
    System.out.print(i);
}
```

Also notice the use of `i--` instead of `i = i - 1`.

---

When you're ready to advance, you may want to have a look at `String.format()` and the `StringBuilder` class and create the full string *before* printing it out.

In principle you can of course use a substring to remove the final `*` character if you first create a string. Or you could remove it from the `StringBuilder` instance if you use that.

I would *still* prefer not appending it in the first place and use above code or a slight modification of it to build the entire string.

Comment: It's working when type  '''System.out.print("\b ");'''  instead of System.out.print("\b");

Comment: That's nice to know. Now don't use that :)